# Issue nesting enum within a struct

Tags: c++, for-loop, struct, enums

I am trying to nest some of my enums within structs so that I can use them in functions involving the other struct variables further down the line. I keep getting an error in the new code `for` loop:

> name followed by a :: must be a class or namespace

However, that's not an issue in the old code `for` loop, which doesn't use classes or namespaces.

Why is the new code throwing up this error? How can I fix it without converting my structs to classes?

oldcode.h

```
const int LONGBUTTON_HEIGHT = 128;
const int LONGBUTTON_WIDTH = 256;

enum CreateForestButtonState { CREATE_DEFAULT, CREATE_HOVER, CREATE_INACTIVE, CREATE_PRESSED, CREATE_TOTAL };
```

oldcode.cpp

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include "oldcode.h"

SDL_Rect create_clips[CreateForestButtonState::CREATE_TOTAL];
for (int i = 0; i < CreateForestButtonState::CREATE_TOTAL; i++)
{
    create_clips[i].x = i * LONGBUTTON_WIDTH;
    create_clips[i].y = 0;
    create_clips[i].w = LONGBUTTON_WIDTH;
    create_clips[i].h = LONGBUTTON_HEIGHT;
}
int useCreate_Clip = CREATE_DEFAULT;
```

newcode.h

```
const int LONGBUTTON_HEIGHT = 128;
const int LONGBUTTON_WIDTH = 256;

struct Graphic
{
    enum state {DEFAULT, HOVER, INACTIVE, PRESSED, TOTAL};
    int use_clip;
    int x;
    int y;
    int h;
    int w;
};
```

newcode.cpp

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include "newcode.h"

Graphic create_plain;
create_plain.type = "long button";
create_plain.state::DEFAULT;
create_plain.use_clip;

SDL_Rect clips[create_plain.state::TOTAL];
for (int i = 0; i < create_plain.state::TOTAL; i++)
{
    clips[i].x = i * LONGBUTTON_WIDTH;
    clips[i].y = 0;
    clips[i].w = LONGBUTTON_WIDTH;
    clips[i].h = LONGBUTTON_HEIGHT;
}
create_plain.use_clip = create_plain.DEFAULT;
```

Comment: `create_plain.state::TOTAL` -> `Graphic::state::TOTAL`

Answer (score 0):

Don't name the enum :

```
struct Graphic
{
    enum {DEFAULT, HOVER, INACTIVE, PRESSED, TOTAL};
    int use_clip;
    int x;
    int y;
    int h;
    int w;
};
```

and

```
SDL_Rect clips[Graphic::TOTAL];
```

Comment: The SDL_Rect part works fine using the struct member create_plain. The error occurs in the for loop: for (int i = 0; i < create_plain.state::TOTAL; i++) "state is underlined - name followed by '::' muist be a class or namespace name.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`for (int i = 0; i < Graphic::state::TOTAL; i++)`

You should use the scope, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

This arrangement works. I don't know why.

```
for (int i = 0; i < create_plain.TOTAL; i++)
```